# Show 2 results for each of 3 different content types

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 8. I have 3 content types: videos, images, and podcasts.

I want to have a single view that shows two of the most recent posts of each content type. For example, out of 4 videos and 2 podcasts, it should show 2 videos, 2 images, and 2 podcasts.

Is this possible? I have been trying to use `hook_views_query_alter()`, but I haven't been able to find a good documentation.

I am currently thinking to use three different views and put them all together.

Comment: It's not really practical to do this in a single view. It would require a fairly complex custom query (the union of three subqueries for example) and honestly it is far simpler to have three views and merge their output in whatever fashion you require.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I ended up using three views instead